# Nginx Autoindex

Tags: nginx, nginx-config

I have a web application running on NGINX and wanted to do some indexing. Basically, the structure is like this:

```
-2021
--Jan
---index.html
--Feb
---index.html
-2020
--Jan
---index.html
--Feb
---index.html
-2019
--index.php
2018
--index.html
```

What I want to do is, whenever I enter the domain name, it will show the list of folders; and, whenever I enter the folder, it will serve the file inside instead of downloading it.

I've tried this:

```
location / {
    charset UTF-8;
    autoindex on;
    autoindex_exact_size on;
    autoindex_format html;
    autoindex_localtime on;
}
```

However, when I click on the 2019 folder, I download instead of opening the page.
Therefore, I try like this:

```
location = / {
    charset UTF-8;
    autoindex on;
    autoindex_exact_size on;
    autoindex_format html;
    autoindex_localtime on;
}
```

This can open the index.php in folder 2019; but, for folders like 2021 and 2020, shows 403 instead of showing list of folders.

So, I added this:

```
location = /2021/ {
    autoindex on;
    autoindex_exact_size off;
    autoindex_format html;
    autoindex_localtime on;
}
location = /2021/ {
    autoindex on;
    autoindex_exact_size off;
    autoindex_format html;
    autoindex_localtime on;
}
```

It works. However, if I try to add another folder, I need to add another config for that folder in nginx. Therefore, I would like a suggestion on how can I add another folder without needing to add another config?

Answer (score 0):

what is you block configuration?

as my as per below works ok, if there is no index file in folder, it show folder with all files and folder and once you open folder with index file, it opens the index file.

```
 server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    server_name domain_name www.domain_name.eu;

    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    root /var/www/domain_name/html;

    autoindex on;

    autoindex_exact_size off;

    autoindex_format html;

    charset UTF-8;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }
}
```

Comment: this works. but if inside the folder have index.php, it will download instead of showing the page

Comment: did you configure the NGINX for the PHP?

here is the few set up needed

https://pimylifeup.com/raspberry-pi-nginx/